# Intermediate executions on CompletableFutures List

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, completable-future

I have a list of completableFutures where each future has varying time of execution(50-300ms).

```
//CompletableFuture[] futures
CompletableFuture<Void> allFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(futures);
allFutures.whenComplete(){
//Do Something
}
```

I want to add an intermediate step where after x ms, where I want to do some partial processing on completed futures, and combine results later

```
//CompletableFuture[] futures
SCHEDULER.schedule(() -> {
for(Future f: futures){
//Do Something else
}
}, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

CompletableFuture<Void> allFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(futures);
allFutures.whenComplete(){
//Do Something
}
```

Above doesn't look pretty to me, is there a better way of doing this, does Completable future have something out of the box for this?

Comment: Why don’t you chain the intermediate action on each future, to be executed immediately after completion, instead of polling the array of all futures? By the way, your current code does not guaranty that the intermediate operation is executed before the final action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be achieved through:

```
CompletableFutures DelayedExecutor 

or using Guava Libraries:

FluentFuture.withTimeout() conversion.
```

Both should be given an executor.